# Firmar documento pdf y poner sello del tiempo

Tags: c#, pdf, firma-digital

necesitaría una pequeña aplicación para firmar un pdf, en principio no hace falta que se vea en el documento, también necesito ponerle un sello del tiempo.
Ver si se puede hacer con un certificado del baul del navegador, o con el fichero pfx + la contraseña.
Se podría hacer tanto de 1 en 1, como si selecciono varios pdf para hacerlo todo al mismo tiempo.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Comentas necesitar una aplicación ¡Perfecto! ¿Y el problema cual es? Debes intentar hacerla y especificar dónde has tenido el problema o dónde te has estancado para ayudarte a hacerla :)

Comment: Hola Rabegi, pues he probado un par de ejemplos con iTextSharp pero ninguno me ha funcionado correctamente, a ver si alguien me puede recomendar algo que funcione en c# y apartir de ahí trastear e ir poniendo las dudas, gracias.

Comment: Pues con lo que llevas de iTextSharp presentalo en la pregunta y menciona en donde esta teniendo problemas o que error se muestra.